# Reading stored procedure result with multiple tables using MVC EF

Tags: json, entity-framework, asp.net-core, stored-procedures

I have searched for similar questions, but they are old.

I am trying to optimize my work by using a stored procedure to retrieve all related tables to one to avoid multiple queries. I want to use this kind of [stored procedure](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/using-stored-procedures-sql-server-return-several-results/) which returns multiple tables as JSON and output parameters, but I am new to ASP.NET Core MVC with EF. Could someone guide me in the right direction? How can I read that output parameter and convert them to objects? it's worth mentioning that I want to use tables for dropLists.

The main table has some columns which are mentioning to some tables. I want to have those table values and show them in some dropdowns or checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was not very hard, maybe someone question in the future:

```
var parameterReturn1 = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "FirstResult",
                SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,
                Size = -1,
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
            };
            var parameterReturn2 = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "SecondResult",
                SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,
                Size= -1,
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
            };

_context.Database
               .ExecuteSqlRaw("exec test @FirstResult output,@SecondResult output", parameterReturn1, parameterReturn2);

            var h2 = parameterReturn2.Value.ToString();      
            var list= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YourObj>>(h2);
```

and in Sp I have something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test2 
@FirstResult NVARCHAR(MAX) OUT, @SecondResult NVARCHAR(MAX) OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

     SELECT @FirstResult =
      (
      SELECT *
        FROM table1
        WHERE customerID = 88164
      FOR JSON AUTO
      );
       SELECT @SecondResult =
      (
      SELECT *
        FROM table2
      
      FOR JSON AUTO
      );
END
GO
```